# make a javafx graphic interface show and hide by sending commands through a socket

Tags: java, javafx

Right now the solution I have is having a queue, and when something comes through the socket putting it the queue and then call stage.hide() or stage.show() depending what it is. But i´m having problem with the implementation. I have something like this:

```
private BlockingQueue<String> requests; 
private Stage primaryStage;

public GraficInterface() {
        requests = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
    }

@Override
    public void start(Stage sp) {
        try {   
            this.primaryStage = sp;
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(...));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.sizeToScene();
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread stopper = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String message;
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        message = requests.take();
                        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("show")) {
                            primaryStage.show();
                        } else if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("hide")) {
                            primaryStage.hide();
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 

                }
            }
        });
        stopper.start();

        launch();   
    }


    public void addToGraficThread(String string) {
        try {
            this.requests.put(string);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Things are working fine with the queue but I´m getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I do `primaryStage.show()` or `primaryStage.hide()`

What I´m trying to do it´s possible? Is there another way?

Comment: You create another instance of your `Application` class when calling `Application.launch`. In addition to this `Application.launch` is responsible for creating the primary stage and invoking the `start` method, which means even if you fix the issue mentioned before, cannot be sure the field has been set from the `start` method (in addition to not ensuring the new field value will eventually be available to the thread and modifying the GUI from a background thread).

Comment: mmmm, so this is not posible? could I Platform.exit() and then launch it again?

Comment: The `Application` class is the entry point of a javafx app, not just responsible for a single window. Many of your issues could be resolved by simply using the `start` method to start to launch a thread starting/handling the socket connection. I recommend using a `Task<Boolean>` though, since it provides functionality for doing updates of it's `value` property on the JavaFX application thread. Exiting and relaunching won't work btw.